# Dynamically create and execute INSERT commands in sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to construct an SQL query for use in sqlite3.
I am however using a `for`loop to construct the query based on the specific parameters needed.

When I attempt to run `execute` for the query, I unfortunately get an error:

> c.execute(sql_query)
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: near " '''INSERT INTO myTable("ID", "1", "2") VALUES(?,?,?) ''' ": syntax error

Here is the full code.

```
import sqlite3, os, re

conn = create_connection(db)
c = conn.cursor()

######### BUILDING SQL QUERY ##############
for file in os.listdir(objExp):
    # Go through each file in the directory, split to remove file extension
    fileID = file.split('.')[0]
    raw_in = input("What values should " + fileID + " have?\n") # input values for this file each seperated by a comma
    num_vals = len(raw_in.split(',')) # Calculate number of values assigned for this file

    if (len(raw_in) == 0):
        # No values to be assigned to this fileID - just add to database with default value (0)
        sql_query = "'''INSERT INTO myTable(\"ID\") VALUES(?)''', (fileID)"
    else:
        # All other cases - meticulously build each section of sqlite3 SQL command
        raw_in = "\"" + raw_in
        raw_in = raw_in + "\""
        raw_in = re.sub(',', '\", \"', raw_in)
        # Values
        values = "VALUES(?,"
        var_chain = "(fileID, "
        for i in range(0,num_vals):
            values = values + "?,"
            var_chain = var_chain + "1, "

        values = re.sub(',$', ')', values)
        var_chain = re.sub(', $', ')', var_chain)
        sql_query = "'''INSERT INTO myTable(\"ID\", " + raw_in + ") " + values + " ''', " + var_chain        
######### END BUILDING SQL QUERY ##############

    print(sql_query)
    c.execute(sql_query)
    conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

The code that builds the SQL query (between the `##### ######`) is correct. I've tested this separately.
I have had a look at `executemany` but I'm not sure it'll work since the length of `VALUES(?....)` is always changing in my case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not the same code that you tested. Tell us exactly what you changed.

Comment: Hi CL. I'm afraid it is the same code I tested. I only changed variable names to make it more readable. I realised some non-conformity with the variable names in the source code so I have updated that in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I do not believe you. Please show the actual test.